# Why am I getting a unique "key" warning when trying to do a map?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting a warning in my android emulator saying that each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.  However, I have a property called key in my children and it's the product id, which should be unique per product.  Does anyone know what else it is trying to say or how I can fix this warning??

```
setModalVisible = (visible) => {      
    const unaddedCartProducts = this.state.unaddedCartItems.map((unaddedCartItem) => {
        return this.props.dispatch(handleLoadProduct(unaddedCartItem.productId).then((result) => {
            return this.setState({unaddedCartItem: result});
        }).then(() => {
            this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
        }))
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
    render() {
        const {isLoading, product} = this.props.products;
        const {unaddedCartItems} = this.state;
        console.log('this.state: ', this.state);
        if (isLoading) {
            return <Loader isVisible={true}/>;
        }

        this.numItems = product.images.length;
        let imageArray = [];
        let circleArray = [];
        product.images.forEach((image, i) => {
            console.log(image, i);
            const thisImage = (
                <Image
                    key={`image${i}`}
                    source={{uri: 'https://b2b.martinsmart.com/productimages/' + image}}
                    style={{width: deviceWidth, borderRadius: 7}}
                    resizeMethod={'scale'}
                    resizeMode={'cover'}
                />
            );
            imageArray.push(thisImage);

            const scrollCircleVal = this.animVal.interpolate({
                inputRange: [deviceWidth * (i - 1), deviceWidth * (i + 1)],
                outputRange: [-8, 8],
                extrapolate: 'clamp',
            });

            const thisCircle = (
                <View
                    key={`circle${i}`}
                    style={[
                        styles.track,
                        {
                            width: 8,
                            height: 8,
                            marginLeft: i === 0 ? 0 : CIRCLE_SPACE,
                            borderRadius: 75

                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    <Animated.View

                        style={[
                            styles.circle,
                            {
                                width: 8,
                                height: 8,
                                borderRadius: 75,
                                transform: [
                                    {translateX: scrollCircleVal},
                                ],
                                backgroundColor: '#FFD200'
                            },
                        ]}
                    />
                </View>
            );
            circleArray.push(thisCircle)
        });
        const listIcon = (<Icon name="list" size={30} style={styles.listIcon}/>);
        const cartIcon = (<Icon name="shopping-cart" size={30}  style={styles.cartIcon} />);
        const questionIcon = (<Icon name="question-circle-o" size={30}  style={styles.questionIcon} />);

        let price = (<Text style={styles.desc}>{'Price: $' + product.price}</Text>);
        let pack = (<Text style={styles.desc}>{'Pk: ' + product.pack + ' x ' + product.averageWeight + 'lb'}</Text>);

        const deliveryEle = (val) => (
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.desc}>Delivery </Text><Text style={styles.desc}>{val}</Text>
            </View>
        );
        const rows = [[price, pack], [deliveryEle('Tue (1/30)')]];
        return (
            <View style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#D6D6D6'}}>
                <Header/>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <View style={{height:'100%', borderRadius: 7}}>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <ScrollView style={{borderRadius: 7}}
                                horizontal
                                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                scrollEventThrottle={10}
                                pagingEnabled
                                onScroll={
                                    Animated.event(
                                        [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this.animVal}}}]
                                    )
                                }
                            >
                                {imageArray}
                            </ScrollView>
                            <View style={styles.listViewContainer}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.listView} onPress={() => Actions.pop()}>
                                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexBasis: 22}}>{listIcon}</View>
                                    <View style={{flex: 2, flexBasis: 57}}><Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>List View</Text></View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                                {circleArray}
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.productsSection}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{product.description}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.desc}>{product.brand}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.desc}>Item: {product.id}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.desc, {marginBottom: 15}]}>Category: {product.category}</Text>
                            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 0}}>
                                <Rows data={rows}/>
                            </Table>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.bodyFooter}>
                            <QuantityCounter style={{width: '100%', display: 'block', marginRight: 20}} data={{productId: product.id}} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <View style={styles.cartContainer}>
                        {cartIcon}
                        <Text style={{color: '#3A3A3A', fontSize: 14}}>18 items</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewCartButtonContainer} onPress={() => this.cartRedirect()}>
                        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, marginTop: '5%'}}>View Cart</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide"
                    transparent={true}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        alert('Modal has been closed.');
                    }}>
                    <View style={styles.modalWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.modal}>
                            <View style={styles.modalHeader}>
                                <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Recovered Items</Text>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible); }}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>CLOSE X</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.subHeader}>
                                {questionIcon}<Text>Did you intend to add the following items?</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.modalBody}>
                            {unaddedCartItems && unaddedCartItems.map(unaddedCartItem =>
                                <CartProductItem
                                    key={unaddedCartItem.id}
                                    product={unaddedCartItem}
                                    onAddToCartClicked={() => addToCart(unaddedCartItem.id)}
                                />
                            )}
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.modalFooter}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.viewCartButtonContainer, {backgroundColor: '#6A6A6A'}]} onPress={() => this.addItems}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, marginTop: '1%'}}>Abandon All</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.viewCartButtonContainer, {backgroundColor: '#5AA958'}]} onPress={() => this.placeOrder}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, marginTop: '1%'}}>Add All</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the render method of `ProductCard`?

Comment: post method of ProductCard

Comment: Yeah, I believe you've misidentified the issue.  The error shoes the line in ProductCard being way later-- that error is usually related to a missing unique key on rendered results of a `.map`.  As the other posters state, include your `render` method and I'm sure someone can give you your answer.

Comment: please post the code not image of code

Comment: Ok I have added my entire render method now.  It's very large so I didn't want to include it originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a unique key value:

```
{unaddedCartItems && unaddedCartItems.map((unaddedCartItem,index) =>
    <CartProductItem
        key={index}
        product={unaddedCartItem}
        onAddToCartClicked={() => addToCart(unaddedCartItem.id)}
    />
)}
```

Thas should resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity

So somewhere in `render()` method of `ProductCard` you are creating an array of elements but you don't specify a `key` prop (which should be a unique and predictable value) for each of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're converting to a *map* an Object who has 3 values.
A map is a set of  `< key , value >`  pairs. In this case you have an object who has:

```
key : 85961
productId : 859610
quentity : 2
```

so your warning is just saying:  *who's the 'key'?*